How to read a PPM with fread "to copy all the pixel data into your array as one large block"
I have an assignment (not for a class that I'm currently taking, but one that I found from a previous year which I'm using for practice) which asks me to use fread to read in the data from a PPM file.
Here is the PPM:
test.ppm
P6
# Created by GIMP version 2.10.24 PNM plug-in
4 4
255
dÿÿÿ¯¯ÿÿÿÿÿ

My copy-past from the file is likely causing issues in how it's rendered here -- I'm not sure if I should try to do anything about that.  But if it's ok, I'll assume that people know that the last line is just "some binary data" and carry on with describing what I'm trying to do.
The assignment was distributed with a certain amount of code, which I should not edit to complete the assignment as it is described.
For one thing, we are given
struct ppm_pixel {
  union {
    struct {
      unsigned char red;
      unsigned char green;
      unsigned char blue;
    };
    unsigned char colors[3];
  };
};

We are also given the following function prototype.
struct ppm_pixel* read_ppm(const char* filename, int* w, int* h)

which we are to implement.  It should return a matrix of pixels (by dynamically allocating space for a 2D array and handling indices so that it stores the pixels in a 2D way).
We are also instructed to "Use fread to copy all the pixel data into your array as one large block".
I think that I could do this if I could read one byte at a time, but I seem to be struggling with reading in everything as one large block, but also using it to construct a matrix of pixels.  Here is what I've written so far.
read_ppm.c
struct ppm_pixel* read_ppm(const char* filename, int* w, int* h) {
  FILE *fp;
    char format[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
    int width, height, maxColorValue;
    struct ppm_pixel *image;

    fp = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        perror("Error opening file");
        return 1;
    }
    
    fscanf(fp, "%s\n", format);
    if (strcmp(format, "P6") != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid PPM format\n");
        fclose(fp);
        return 1;
    }
    
    char line[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
    fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp);
    while (line[0] == '#') {
        fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp);
    }
    
    *w = atoi(strtok(line, " "));
    *h = atoi(strtok(NULL, " "));
    fscanf(fp, "%d\n", &maxColorValue);
    
    image = malloc(width * height * sizeof(struct ppm_pixel));
    if (image == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation failed\n");
        fclose(fp);
        return 1;
    }
    
    fread(image, 3*8, width * height, fp);
    
    fclose(fp);
    fp = NULL;

    return image;
}

I know that it's wrong, even the types mismatch with image receiving the raw data rather than a struct ppm_pixel instance.
But that's precisely the issue -- how could one both "read in as one block" and also structure it into a pixel and then assign the pixel into the matrix?  I suppose you could read in the raw data into a second matrix and then copy from the second matrix into the image, but that seems insanely wasteful of memory and time, no?

Just to make sure the exact question I'm asking is clear, I'll state it separately.
How can you read the data in as one block, using fread, and also structure it into a ppm_pixel struct, and assign the ppm_pixel to the matrix?  Should this be done by allocating the data to yet another matrix, or is there a simpler and more efficient way?

Where did 3*8 in the fread() call come from? That should be sizeof(struct ppm_pixel) just like in the malloc() call.

Other than that, your method of reading it all in one call is correct.

@Barmar Yes, it's wrong, it was just what I wrote while in the middle of trying to figure things out.  Only after I submitted the question did I realize that the struct is defined a little differently than it was in a previous related assignment, and perhaps I'm supposed to exploit this difference to do a direct write into the array.  Anyway, when I submitted the question I knew the code was wrong, I just didn't know how to approach the problem correctly.  But I may now have a sense of how to do it, and I need to continue thinking about it.

After thinking and working on it more, I still can't get it to work.  When I replace 3*8 with sizeof(struct ppm_pixel) it puts nonsense in the matrix.  The print out in the console is r:1629630480 g:0 b:28   r:1625096223 g:0 b:1 and so on with values not found in the data.  I'm guessing that somehow the reading is misaligned by a byte or so but I don't know why or how to debug that.

Mixing fread() with fscanf() could be a problem. Try using only fgets() to read the text lines.

The calculate 3*8 was an attempt to reason that each bit is a byte and they'd be separated by a space and there are three of them.  It similarly produces nonsense though.

@Barmar I wondered if that were the issue, thanks!  I'll try it.

Although, a worry might be: aren't some PPM files not separated by line breaks?  So if a PPM were separated only by white space this might not work?

Er, maybe the header is always split by line breaks but the data is not -- I'll continue researching.

https://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/ppm.html

I finally got it working, likely in large part because of the comments from @Barmar.  If they would like to post an answer, I'd be happy to accept it and give them credit.
I think there might have been two mistakes, one with using fscanf so when I instead worked with fgets I think this made fread track the proper position in the file correctly.  Also I just made a dumb mistake when printing the values in the matrix.

Oh, also, I changed the number of bytes to read to 3*4 just because I was worried that perhaps sizeof(struct ppm_pixel) might have been returning the wrong number of bytes since it is a union data structure and ... I dunno, maybe it was fine.  But running it with manual calculation of the number of bytes worked (on my hardware, your mileage may vary).

struct ppm_pixel* read_ppm(const char* filename, int* w, int* h) {
  FILE *fp;
    char format[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
    int width, height, maxColorValue;
    struct ppm_pixel *image;

    fp = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        perror("Error opening file");
        return 1;
    }
    
    fgets(format, sizeof(format), fp);
    if (strcmp(format, "P6\n") != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid PPM format\n");
        fclose(fp);
        return NULL;
    }
    
    char line[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
    fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp);
    while (line[0] == '#') {
        fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp);
    }
    
    *w = atoi(strtok(line, " "));
    *h = atoi(strtok(NULL, " "));
    fscanf(fp, "%d\n", &maxColorValue);
    
    image = malloc(width * height * sizeof(struct ppm_pixel));
    if (image == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation failed\n");
        fclose(fp);
        return 1;
    }
    
    fread(image, 3*4, width * height, fp);
    
    fclose(fp);

    return image;
}


Go ahead and post your code as a solution.

@Addem Tip: width * height * sizeof(struct ppm_pixel) better as sizeof(struct ppm_pixel) * width * height as size_t math is less likely to overflow than int math.  (and width * height --> (size_t) width * height)
